# Using .includes on more than one aspect of a prop in Vue to build a search

Tags: laravel, vue.js, search

I'm trying to create a very basic fuzzy search that uses the values of an object in props. The below search works fine, but only checks for `speciality.name`

How would I modify this to allow for it to check not only `candidate.speciality.name` but other values from inside `candidate`? i.e. how would I go about letting check for example `candiate.firstname` **and** `candidate.speciality` ?
Script

```
    export default {
    props: ['profiles'],

    data() {
        return {
            search: ''
        }
        
    },

    computed: {
        filteredList() {
        return this.profiles.filter(candidate => {
            return candidate.speciality.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        })
        }
    }

}
```

Template

```
<template>

<div>

    <input type="text" v-model="search">

    <div v-for="candidate in filteredList" :key="candidate.id">

        <admin-profile-entry :candidate="candidate" :speciality="candidate.speciality.name"></admin-profile-entry>

    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `or` condition in your computed property:

```js
filteredList() {
  const searchTerm = this.search.toLowerCase()
  return this.profiles.filter(candidate => {
    return candidate.speciality.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
           candidate.firstname.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
  })
}
```

Comment: Oh Gosh-Hecking-Darn it... don't you just love it when it's that simple! I feel so stupid. Thank you!